# Simplify multi-level aggregation in MySQL8?

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, common-table-expression

I need to run aggregate statistics on a table using multiple levels of aggregation.

An inelegant method of achieving this would be to `UNION` several `SELECT` queries using same field names, but each with a different fields in the query's `GROUP BY`.

Example: Aggregate sum of population for each municipality (=smallest geographical unit), county, nation and world, ie grand total of the `population` field.

```sql
-- aggregate dummy table population_statistics by 
-- 1:municipality 2:county 3:nation 4:world

SELECT 
    "municipality" AS geo_level, 
    municipality_name AS geo_name, 
    SUM(population) AS population
FROM population_statistics 
GROUP BY municipality_name 

UNION 

SELECT 
    "county" AS geo_level, 
    county_name AS geo_name, 
    SUM(population) AS population
FROM population_statistics   
GROUP BY county_name 

UNION 

SELECT 
    "nation" AS geo_level, 
    country_name AS geo_name, 
    SUM(population) AS population
FROM population_statistics
GROUP BY country_name

UNION 

SELECT 
    "world" AS geo_level, 
    "world" AS geo_name, 
    SUM(population) AS population
FROM population_statistics
;
```

[DB-fiddle with mock-up data](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3tT7x7um43CZHtjorRmBqF/1)

I know that programming languages such as R's `tidyr` and python's `pandas` libraries have cleaner ways of running multiple level aggregation of tables. **But is it possible to run multiple level aggregations using pure SQL?** Perhaps Common Table Expressions (CTEs, which was recently added to MySQL version 8) may be used make such aggregations more efficient?

Comment: this has nothing inelegant , it is a common way to join Tables vertically

Comment: Can you post sample data of the table `population_statistics`?

Comment: @forpas, `population_statistics` is imagined table to illustrate the (data warehouse) concept of multi-level aggregation. It should probably not be necessary to run code to illustrate best practise for multi-level aggregation.

Comment: @HaraldGroven this is not multi-level aggregation. It is 1st level aggregation applied more than once to the same table. I asked for sample data because you want to simplify your code.

Comment: Yes, it is obvious that it is four 1st level aggregations. But is it possible to rewrite as a single multi-level aggregation in SQL (as some programming languages support) ? This is useful both for aggregating by hierarchical levels (such as the geography example here) or time (aggregate by year, month, week and day).

Answer (score 1):

In MySql 8.0+ you can create a CTE with all the levels that you want to aggregate and then apply aggregation:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 1 sort_order, 'municipality' geo_level, municipality_name geo_name, population FROM population_statistics
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'county', county_name, population FROM population_statistics
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'nation', country_name, population FROM population_statistics
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'world', 'world', population FROM population_statistics  
)
SELECT geo_level, geo_name, SUM(population) population
FROM cte
GROUP BY sort_order, geo_level, geo_name
ORDER BY sort_order
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dcf5a4f98ffa2edebe4ea839289552ee).